# How to access the static Resource file for input

Tags: unit-test

I have static Resource file named as http res.txt as the input as Json format
How to access the file named in the input of Http callout in webservice method

I want to use the input in the

singleRequestMock fakeResponse = new SingleRequestMock(**here i have to use that static Resource how?**);

Please anyone Guide me for the Answer

```
@isTest

global class SingleRequestMock implements HttpCalloutMock {

        protected Integer code;

        protected String status;

        protected String bodyAsString;

        protected Blob bodyAsBlob;

        protected Map<String, String> responseHeaders;



        public SingleRequestMock(Integer code, String status, String body,

                                         Map<String, String> responseHeaders) {

            this.code = code;

            this.status = status;

            this.bodyAsString = body;
            this.bodyAsBlob = null;

            this.responseHeaders = responseHeaders;

        }


        public SingleRequestMock(Integer code, String status, Blob body,

                                         Map<String, String> responseHeaders) {

            this.code = code;

            this.status = status;

            this.bodyAsBlob = body;

            this.bodyAsString = null;

            this.responseHeaders = responseHeaders;

        }



        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

            HttpResponse resp = new HttpResponse();

            resp.setStatusCode(code);

            resp.setStatus(status);

            if (bodyAsBlob != null) {

                resp.setBodyAsBlob(bodyAsBlob);

            } else {

                resp.setBody(bodyAsString);

            }



        if (responseHeaders != null) {

             for (String key : responseHeaders.keySet()) {

            resp.setHeader(key, responseHeaders.get(key));

             }

        }

        return resp;

    }
```

}

Please Guide me the answer according to this Class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wouldn't need to use this "SingleCalloutMock" class at all. Instead, you can use [StaticResourceCalloutMock](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_staticresourcecalloutmock.htm), as follows:

```
StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
mock.setStatus('OK');
mock.setStatusCode(200);
mock.setStaticResource('res');
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);
```

You can read more about it in [Testing HTTP Callouts Using Static Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_static.htm). There's no need to create your own custom class when you use this class, as it is part of the platform.

If you really wanted to stick with SingleCalloutMock, you can query the [StaticResource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_staticresource.htm) object to retrieve the data:

```
StaticResource resource = [SELECT Body FROM StaticResource WHERE DeveloperName='myResourceName'];
```

You could then pass the Body value in to your class. Please note that doing it this way consumes a query, while using StaticResourceCalloutMock is essentially free in terms of governor limits.

Comment: In the _Test.setMock()_, isn't it a interface that you should use as a parameter, like _HttpCalloutMock.class_?
I got an "System.TypeException: Supplied type is not an interface" error when I tried running your code.

Comment: @tak971 you're absolutely right. I'm not sure how I missed this. I amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
singleRequestMock fakeResponse = new SingleRequestMock();
fakeResponse.setStaticResource('httpres.txt');
fakeResponse.setStatusCode(...);
fakeResponse.setHeader(...);
....
```

Take some time to look into the following Trailhead which demonstrates [Apex Rest Callout](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts).

An example of Static Resource access is also given within the above Trailhead.

Comment: I have written another to generate the Mock response automatically @ so i need Parameter in the Fake response how?